# Page transition delay after link is clicked (after animation end)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I searched for similar problems but none of the solutions didn't help me.

So, here is my problem, i have in my header a few link for other pages (about, porftiolio etc...) and i have one animation in javascript when `<a>` element is clicked. But my page transition is instantly so that animation can't be seen. So what should i do to maybe stop page transition for a few second till my animation's end. Here is an **example:**  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrXrXM . Can somebody help me what should i do to stop transition until my animation ends.

Comment: you could do a redirection after the animation instead of a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preventDefault` to stop the re-direct, then change the `window.location` on the animation `complete`.

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(".header").slideUp("slow", function(){
      window.location = href; 
    });
});
```

[**Updated CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKdeJM)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setTimeout()` function
look here: http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/Ejxvjr
Explain here:http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-settimeout-function-examples/

Comment: for page transition or animation ?

Comment: your problem is that your page is loaded to soon, isn't it. So use it for page transition.